Shorter way to define contextmanager by decorator?
When creating a decorator using @contextlib.contextmanager(), we have to write
enter_action(...)
try:
    yield ...
finally:
   exit_action(...)

That is 3 lines just for the (rather unaesthetic) try/yield/finally construct.
Why can't we get something like this instead?
enter_action(...)
with context_magic(...):  # equivalent to try/yield/finally
    exit_action(...)

Would that be technically possible?

Maybe through a function_name.magic trick, so the @contextmanager wrapper can get the code point or something? I guess not, though...

Which part of your template would contain the try: block? The idea isn't without merit but you have probably simplified it too far.

Enter action returns a context value, and you example lacks indication of propagating it. Also exit action is supposed to handle context body errors, and you have no error handling. So no, this approach would only be possible for a reduced feature set of contexts.

@Basilevs The context value would be passed to the context_magic constructor.

Aesthetically, it seems pretty natural to me to yield a context object for use and then finally do cleanup even if errors occur.

@CrazyChucky I agree it's not a big deal, but it seemed unnecessary to carry around in every calling code, and something that could be outsourced into the contextmanager decorator directly.

We can delegate the try/finally wrapping to a custom decorator:
import contextlib

def short_ctxmanager(func):
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def wrapped(*args, **kws):
        gen = func(*args, **kws)
        out = next(gen)
        try:
            yield out
        finally:
            try:
                next(gen)
            except StopIteration:
                pass
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Context manager cannot have more than 1 yield.")
    return wrapped

@short_ctxmanager
def my_ctx():
    print("enter")
    yield
    print("exit (always executed)")

def test():
    with my_ctx():
        raise RuntimeError("exit should still run")

test()

This prints:
enter
exit (always executed)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/projects/ctx.py", line 29, in <module>
    test()
  File "/home/me/projects/ctx.py", line 27, in test
    raise RuntimeError("exit should still run")
RuntimeError: exit should still run

CC Why do we need "try-finally" when using @contextmanager decorator?
I think the with thingy I initially imagined in the question may not work, though, because I see no way to interrupt this to run the caller's code, and come back to the exit handler afterwards. Only yield can do that.

The exception does not reach the line print("exit (always executed)"), it always bubbles up. I guess this is still useful, because I never use the capability to intercept exceptions of normal context managers.

@Basilevs Unfortunately, that's true, this loses the ability to catch and handle exceptions from the caller's with-block in the context manager function. It just makes sure the exit handler is always executed, which as you say may still be a useful shortcut.
This explains why contextlib.contextmanager does not provide implicit try/finally out of the box, though.

@Basilevs Actually, there is an approach, but it's not very nice. One can capture the exception in the wrapper and propagate it back with gen.throw() (while catching StopIteration), so the caller can handle exceptions with an optional, second yield statement. However, this messes up order, so you may be better advised to use the raw @contextmanager and try/except/finally construct.

What we would need is basically a generator where we could call next() even after .throw() in a superordinate finally clause.

Contexts provide a target (a value returned from __enter__() method) and an error handling (by __exit__() method). Neither of these features are handled by your example.
So while it is possible to design a language where such example would work, its context managers would have a reduced feature set.
